# Rails: How can I set or toggle admin status without mass assignment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating what is essentially a public-facing site with a protected admin backend (i.e. the only users will be the admins themselves).

As my app stands now, users can be created via the app (though Users#new and Users#edit are **accessible *only* to existing admins**).  In keeping with security best practices, I've kept my `:admin` boolean attribute out of my `attr_acessible`, so a user's admin status cannot be assigned or toggled via mass assignment.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

end
```

I'm currently only able to assign admin status via the console, but I'd like for my clients to be able to create new users and give them admin status from within the app.

How would I handle the equivalent of `user.toggle!(:admin)` from within the app, *without* mass assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a great tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible) which fits your needs.

Comment: I'll take a look at this, as it seems like it'll suit me.  Thanks for the link... I'll report back with results.

Comment: It worked perfectly, and I can see how this is going to be useful for a lot of other ends as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CanCan gem to set user permissions. I think this would take care of your issue w/o mass assignment:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/cancan/1.6.5/frames

Comment: The further I get into this process, the more I'm wishing I'd used the CanCan gem from the start!  Unfortunately, this is the last piece of the puzzle for my own system, so I'd rather not install a gem just for this.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

try to use namespaced controllers for admin's purposes and do #update_attbute in controllers instead of forms